# How get $@ in makefile like shell scripting

Tags: makefile

&&How to get the args after running "make" or "make all"?

Right now i have:

```
all:echo

target=$(filter-out all,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

echo:
    @echo $(target)
```

Result:

```
  make abc
  make: *** No rule to make target `abc'.  Stop.
  &&
  make all abc
  abc
  make: *** No rule to make target `abc'.  Stop.
```

Desired result:

```
   make abc
   abc
   &&
   make all abc
   abc
```

Comment: Those aren't "arguments" those are other targets. You can get them with the filter you have but make is still going to try to build them.

Comment: There is actually no rule (even not a generated one) for `abc`, what else did you expect (your desired result doesn't explain this clearly)? Also, why did you tag this question with [tag:cmake]? Are you writing your makefiles actually or are they generated?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your use-case and it seems strange, but here's a solution which might help you:

```
target=$(filter-out all,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
$(info $(target))

.PHONY: $(target)
all $(target):
    @:
```

To explain: `make abc` does not trigger the target `all`, therefore not triggering `echo` in your attempt. If you always want to see the value of `target`, use `$(info ...)`.

In order to suppress the "No rule to make target ...", you need to explicitly let make (I actually only tested GNUmake) know that there is such a target and there is nothing to do. This is what the last part of the above is about. `.PHONY:` lists targets which are only a symbol and do not refer to an actual file. You then need a rule for those targets (and for `all`) which does nothing. `@:` does that: The `@` makes sure the command is not echoed and `:` is just the shell's way of a no-op.